# Why doesn't phx.new create my elixir project with the latest elixir version?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I use the [asdf package manager](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) and when I run the command `asdf current elixir`, it returns `1.9.1    (set by /Users/my_user/.tool-versions)`.

I created a project with the command `mix phx.new my_project --no-ecto` and when I open the `mix.exs` file, my settings are:

```
def project do
    [
      app: :pedal,
      version: "0.0.1",
      elixir: "~> 1.4",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
end
```

Why does my elixir version at my project is 1.4 if my elixir version at my computer is 1.9.1?

Comment: The Elixir version specified in your `mix.exs` file is not the version that your project will run on. It is the minimum supported version for your project. So the version of phoenix that your `phx.new` task generates still supports Elixir 1.4+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you used: `mix phx.new my_project --no-ecto` is going to decide what is minimal version of Elixir it's gonna use, in that case is going to be `1.4`, because it's the version used for Phoenix.

You can install the last version of Phoenix to make sure you're using the last minimal version of Elixir is uses as well.

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/installation.html